# Configure a scheduled task on .war file created by Spring/Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, cron

I have an application developed on **spring framework** with **maven**. I have many modules (each one has its own **pom.xml** file) and I have the generic **pom.xml** to compile the entire project.

Using **maven** I compile a `.war` file and I deploy this one in a **Jetty** server, but now I have another problem. I need to configure a function that will execute some code every couple of minutes.
I tried to configure it like [at the following link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks), so having:

I edited the specific pom.xml file and I add this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

On dependencies list, I added this in plugin list:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

I created in the same module one file that defined this class:

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        log.info("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work for me. Logs don't print anything.
I've been struggling with this issue for a while but I didn't manage to find any solution also taking a look at other related Q/A on StackOverflow.

**What Am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix by replacing `@Component` with `@Service` and `@EnableScheduling`.

```
@Service
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduledTasks {
    . . .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need EnableScheduling in your main config

```
@EnableScheduling
.....
..... other config annotaions
public class ApplicationConfig {
}
```

Comment: I forgot to write that I created another class like you can see at the [the following link](https://gist.github.com/marnone9/01a2dabe39632e6885c0fd4a11f3c725)

Comment: Do you have your logging set up correctly, add a System.out or step through it in the debugger.

Comment: I've tried to make a log in a rest service of the same package and it works

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `@EnableScheduling` and `SpringBootServletInitializer` in your Spring Boot application class to make the scheduler work when you deploy the war file on tomcat.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

}
```

then just add a method with @Scheduled annotation in a spring managed bean.

```
@Service
public class MyService{

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60_000)
    public void runEveryMinute(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```